# iPhone Objective C oauth 2.0 Login - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: iphone, oauth, salesforce, nsurlrequest, oauth-2.0

I am brand new to salesforce development and am trying to connect to Salesforce to get the token.

I guess my question is 2 fold: 
1) Do I have to use a webpage to authenticate with SF?

2) If not, why is this not working?  When I try to use the username and password method of authenticating, I get:
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}

Here is my code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=basic-credentials&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@",
                  kOAuthClientID,
                  kOAuthClientSecret,
                  kOAuthClientAuthURL
                  ];


NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kOAuthClientTokenUrl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSLog(@"%@", request);
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Any thoughts would be welcome.

I did try using grant_type = authorization_code but got another error:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid authorization
>   code"}

Comment: hi, can u plz tell what does kOAuthClientAuthURL & kOAuthClientTokenUrl stands for and how were u finally able to get it working, coz the answer by "superfell" doesnt seem to be working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the username/password grant type, then its type is password not basic-credentials, the correct set of parameters to send are

```
grant_type=password
client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
client_secret=1234567890
username=noreply@salesforce.com
password=XXXXXXXXX
```

As i mentioned in your previous question, although this works, you really do want to use the web based flow so as to support salesforce customers that are using alternative login services like SAML.

Comment: when i used the above mentioned parameters i got the error "unsupported_response_type", i provided it. then i got the error saying redirected uri missing, i then provided the OAuth2 success uri of salesforce. still i get some weird response which is not either session id or token, a little help required :(

Comment: What URL are you sending it to, and you also need to URL encode all the parameters, which you don't appear to be doing.

Comment: i m sending the salesforce success url, i.e. https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success. And i m encoding everything in url formal. some help plz

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you do, with OAuth you need to sign into Salesforce and grant your application access. For an iOS app, you'd be looking at the client flow [Salesforce OAuth Client Flow Doc](https://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm)

2) Take a look at the Toolkit for iOS on [the Force.com developer site](http://developer.force.com). There is a class called ZKOAuthViewController that pretty much does it all for you. The rest of the tooklit is based around Force.com's SOAP API but I just made my own OAuth login controller based on the toolkits and use the REST API instead.

Comment: 1) So you are saying that I have to open a UIWebView in my app to get the token? Is there any way around this?  I thought you could use the direct username and password method - https://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm#up_obtain_access_token

Comment: Yeah, you can use the username and password method but then you'd need to embed the client key and secret in your code which isn't recommended.

Comment: 2) I can't find ZKOAuthViewController

Comment: [Link to file on GitHub](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-iOS/blob/master/ZKSforce/ZKOAuthViewController.h)

Answer (score 1):

Superfell's answer is nearly correct. The password needs to be set to:

password + security token

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm for extra info.